# Extract a substrng in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a path **D:\Test\IL_2014-07\Dev** in a variable $path.
I want to extract only ***07*** from path mentioned above.
I have tried various options with `Select-String` cmdlet, but nothing is working.

Can anybody suggest what could be possible command to extract ***07***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the -replace command to trim off all the parts you don't want:

```
$var = 'D:\Test\IL_2014-07\Dev'
$var -replace '.+\d{4}-(\d{2}).+','$1'
07
```

Comment: @mjolinor, can u pls provide small elaboration on how you use these wild cards as I need to use same concept for others as well

Comment: Those aren't wildcards.  That's a regular expression.  See get-help about_Regular_Expressions for a brief tutorial.  That should provide enough information to get you started.